# SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ") parse in java gives wrong date?

Tags: java, parsing, datetime, simpledateformat, java.util.date

I used this `SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")`.So when I pass date `2016-01-01T10:30:00-0800` more than or equal to 10:30:00-0800 time then it will parse(date) response which is next day date 2016-01-02T00:00:00+0530 which is not expected.It changes date by one day.If I give 2016-01-01T10:20:00-0800 then give exact date.So if time should be less t10:30:00-0800 then get expected result otherwise next day date.

Full code:

```
SimpleDateFormat dt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
public Date deserialize(JsonParser jsonparser, DeserializationContext arg1)   {
  String date = jsonparser.getText();
  dt.parse(date);
}
```

Comment: What is your locale?

Comment: @abhay app servers runs on UTC time and local machine India

Comment: Show your code that demonstrates the exact problem.

Comment: @Jesper parse method returns next day date

Comment: Edit your question above and add the code; posting code in comments doesn't work very well.

Comment: @BalusC Do you have any solution on this?

Comment: @Jesper -0800 what actually do means date is 1 jan 2016 time 18:30:00 means 6:30p.m. but what -0800 actually do?

Comment: @Abhay I think you mean “What is your time zone?”, not locale.

Answer (score 3):

It's important to understand that an instance of the class `java.util.Date` is not a calendar date but a moment in time.

Converting a `java.util.Date` to and from a string representation always involves time zones.

Your input is `2016-01-01T10:30:00-0800`, indicating a zone offset of -8 hours (which is the timezone of Los Angeles, USA). That moment in time corresponds to `2016-01-01T18:30:00+0000` in a zone with an offset of 0 hours (like London, GB) or to `2016-01-02T00:00:00+0530` within your local time zone.

That is fine if you want to store the moment a meeting in Los Angeles begins and show that moment in different time zones.

If you want to represent dates (like birthdays) that have no inherent time information you should better use `java.time.LocalDate` (if you are using Java 8) or `org.joda.time.LocalDate` (if Java 8 is not an option).

Comment: If users are from different zones so if request date is as per his local timezone then date need to set for that project is as per his local zone or as per UTC time.because it may happen same date for USA user have 1 jan it will be next day for indian user.users from worldwide seeing that date.

Answer (score 0):

## java.time

You are using old outmoded date-time classes that have proven to be poorly designed, confusing, and troublesome. Use java.time instead.

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the old troublesome date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`. The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) team also advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to Android in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

## ISO 8601

Your input string complies with [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. These standard formats are used by default in java.time classes. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

## Offset

Your input value has an offset-from-UTC, a number of 8 hours behind UTC.

The `OffsetDateTime` class represents such values.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( "2016-01-01T10:30:00-0800" );
```

## Time zone

A time zone is an offset-from-UTC *plus* a set of rules for handling anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST). If you are certain of the time zone intended as the context for this value, apply it to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

Specify a time zone (`ZoneId`) by a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) in format of `continent/region`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviations such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, are not standardized, and are not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Los_Angeles" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZone( zoneId );
```

## Change time zone

If you want to see this value through the lens of local [time in India](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_India), you can apply a different time zone to create a new [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html). The java.time classes use the [immutable objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) pattern. So note that rather than alter (“mutate”) the time zone setting on an existing object, the java.time classes create a new object with some of its members based on the original object’s members.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt_Kolkata = zdt.withZoneSameInstant( ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ) ;
```

Comment: I can not change java version 7 to 8 so for java 7 any alternative do you have?